# Filter Pivot Tables with Checkbox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub checkboxfilter()
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim oWB As Workbook
    Dim oPvt As PivotTable
    Dim oPvtField As PivotField
    Dim oPvtFilter As PivotFilter


    Set cb = oWS("Control").Controls("YTD Filter")

If cb.Value = True Then
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each oPvt In oWS
           With oPvtField
           .CurrentPage.Name = "Yes"
           End With
        Next oPvt
    Next oWS
 End If

End Sub
```

the goal is to toggle each pivot table in the workbook by a yer-to-date filter via checkbox. The code hits a snag under `set cb=` as an object variable or with not set. What am I missing here to get this control working? I'm also avoiding the use of a slicer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of control has it's own event and you should use it. Therefore:

1. go to sheet where you have your checkbox
2. set `Design mode` on developer tab on
3. double click on you `check box` to ...
4. ...see something like `Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()`
5. inside that sub call your subroutine:

   ```
   Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
        call   checkboxfilter
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't solve the filtering with the above code though.

Comment: you asked how to trigger action with check box :) when looking into your code it seems that you still have to link your `oPvt` with pivot fields. at this moment `oPvtField` seems to be `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to revise based on adjusting the type of format the `set cb =` as a `.Checkboxes` and ensuring at each pivot fielt was accurately called as @KazimierzJawor pointed out. Additionally with this type the value needed to be a 0 or 1 rather than `True` or `False`. Corrected and final code below.

```
Private Sub checkboxfilter()
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim oWB As Workbook
    Dim oPvt As PivotTable
    Dim oPvtField As PivotField
    Dim oPvtFilter As PivotFilter


Set cb = Sheets("Control").CheckBoxes("YTD Filter")

If cb.Value = 1 Then
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each oPvt In oWS.PivotTables
           With oPvt.PivotFields("YTD?")
           .CurrentPage = "Yes"
           End With
        Next oPvt
    Next oWS
    Else
            For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each oPvt In oWS.PivotTables
               With oPvt.PivotFields("YTD?")
               .CurrentPage = "(All)"
               End With
            Next oPvt
        Next oWS
 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub PivotFilter()    
    Dim pvtF As PivotField
    Dim pvtI As PivotItem
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim pvtIVal As String
    StartDate = DateValue("Jan 1, 2018")
    EndDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create Month").ClearAllFilters
    Set pvtF = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Create Month")
    For Each pvtI In pvtF.PivotItems
    If (pvtI <> "(blank)") Then
    If DateValue(pvtI) >= StartDate And DateValue(pvtI) <= EndDate Then
    pvtI.Visible = True
    Else
    pvtI.Visible = False
    End If
    Else
    pvtI.Visible = False
    End If
    Next pvtI
    End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.